# Is it a sin if my private part was exposed to a medical professional unintentionally?

Tags: awrah, modesty

Assalamualaikum.

I am a male Muslim & had a question regarding covering of private parts.

A few days back, I met with an accident & I went to the hospital. In the hospital, they examined me and gave me an injection. While giving the injection the wardboy asked me to loosen my pants. But even after loosening it, the pants were tights so he tried to pulled my tried to pants little down but accidentally he pulled my underwear and a little of my private part was exposed which he touched it accidentally.

**After that incident I am feeling awkward and inconvenient. Has something wrong  occurred???**

Comment: It happens to a lot of people each day so what should be wrong here?

Comment: Firstly, incase of a medical emergency it is permissible to show your awrah to a doctor ideally of the same gender. Secondly, in your case, it was unintentional on your part. Inshallah either way, no sin was committed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do you get sin for doing something unintentionally?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/60802/do-you-get-sin-for-doing-something-unintentionally)

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not a sin if you are on an emergency state, Allah knows what best and the most merciful.